# JavaScript OOP. Trying to study OOP in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below is a simple JavaScript OOP that I am trying to understand.  I want to know why `getA()` and `getC()` return undefined, but the same `getB()` returns 2 when I change the variable `B` in the constructor and assign it to the `b`.

When I run `getD()` it returns, what I am assigning?  How is `this` working here?

```
var a,b,c,d;

var encap = function(a,B,c,d){
    a = a;
    b = B;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
}

encap.prototype.getA = function() {
    return a; // returns undefined
};

encap.prototype.getB = function() {
    return b; // returns 2
};

encap.prototype.getC = function() {
    return c; // undefined
};

encap.prototype.getD = function() {
    return this.d;
};


encap.prototype.setA = function(A) {
    a = A;
};

encap.prototype.setB = function(B) {
    b = B;
};


var encapObj = new encap(1,2,4,6);

console.log(encapObj.getA());  // undefined
console.log(encapObj.getB());  // 2
console.log(encapObj.getC());  // undefined
console.log(encapObj.getD());  // 6
```

Comment: JavaScript is a fine language to learn OOP, just not classical inheritance.

Comment: Maybe , can you please explain above... i working in javascript only.

Comment: `a = a` doesn't assign to the global a, it assigns to the local one. Those global vars really shouldn't exist in any real scenario.

Comment: JavaScript is a prototype based language, object oriented concepts are created on top of the prototype chain. Have a look at this article to learn more about how the two concepts relate: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/prototype.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, I commented every assignment of what variable is being assigned where.

This should help explain things.

```
// Create four global variables.
var a,b,c,d;

var encap = function(a,B,c,d){
    // Assign local argument a, to local argument a.  Does nothing
    a = a;

    // Assign local argument "B" to global variable "b"
    b = B;

    // assign local argument 'c' to property 'c'
    this.c = c;

    // assign local argument 'd' to property 'd'
    this.d = d;
}

encap.prototype.getA = function() {
    // Returns global variable a
    return a; // returns undefined
};

encap.prototype.getB = function() {
    // Return global variable B, which was assigned in the constructor
    return b; // returns 2
};

encap.prototype.getC = function() {
    // Return global variable 'c'
    return c; // undefined
};

encap.prototype.getD = function() {
    // return object property 'd', which was assigned.
    return this.d;
};


encap.prototype.setA = function(A) {
    // assign global variable 'a' from argument 'A'
    a = A;
};

encap.prototype.setB = function(B) {
    // assign global variable 'b' from argument 'B'
    b = B;
};


var encapObj = new encap(1,2,4,6);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy , // Create four local variables.
var a,b,c,d;  is it local or global? i thought it's global. Best Javascript prototype Example Including private & public variables , methods. Explaining the context of "this". i searched over internet , many has many ways. it will be lot if you give me example. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll assume that first "local" was a typo. *Edited*

Answer (score 5):

```
a = a;
```

This assigns to the local variable `a` from the local variable `a`, effectively (ineffectively?) doing nothing. The global variable is still set to its default of `undefined`, and that’s why you get `undefined` from `getA()`.

In `getC()`, you return the value of the global variable `c`, but only assigned to the property `c` of the instance: `this.c`. `this` isn’t implicit in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so here's the deal. You have four global variables:

```
var a, b, c, d;
```

You also have four variables that are local to the constructor

```
var encap = function(a,B,c,d);
```

Then you also have two "instance" variables - variables that are attached to the new object when it's created.

```
this.c = c;
this.d = d;
```

In the constructor, you set `a = a` - this is really just setting the local variable (parameter) `a` to itself. You're accessing the local variable from the constructor on both sides of the `=`. In your accessor `getA`, you return the *global* variable `a` - which is undefined.

Also in the constructor you set the value of global variable `b` equal to the value of local variable `B` - remember that they're different because JavaScript is case-sensitive. So, your global variable `b` now has a value of `2`. Since, again, you return the *global* variable in your accessor `getB`, you get the value `2`.

In your accessor `getC`, you still return the *global* variable `c` - which was never set. Hence `undefined`. However, this time you set `this.c` in the constructor, so if you were to `return this.c` in your accessor, you should get the correct value.

In summary, you should probably be using `this` on all your variable assignments and returns. so, your constructor should look like the following:

```
var encap = function(a,B,c,d){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = B;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
}
```

And your accessors should look like this:

```
encap.prototype.getD = function() {
    return this.d;
};
```

From there, I think it's pretty obvious what your setters should look like. Good luck in your exploration of OOP in JavaScript. It's my favorite language, and I love its OOP, despite what anybody says about it. If you have trouble, the StackOverflow JS chat room is often helpful, so come on in some time.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, What about private variables in OOP, if i am giving this.a = a, so when creating a object , that a will accessible outside the class?   i also have another question . By using this.a , whether i am accessing a global "a" or it's local context of the object.

Comment: When you use `this.a` you're accessing the object. `this` can be kind of a strange concept in JS, but those are the basics. Private don't really exist, though you can use closures to simulate something like private variables. In my experience, it's best to just let go of the idea of "private"

Comment: I can, in fact... I wrote a short series on [Blogascript](http://blog.javascriptroom.com). Start with [Objects and the Prototype Chain](http://blog.javascriptroom.com/2013/01/14/objects-and-the-prototype-chain/).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should know: Javascript is fully object oriented language there is no OOP "way" in javascript. Everything execpt primitive types ( undefined, number, string, boolean, null ) is an object.